# One liner Linux/bash to print a complex statement

Tags: bash

I have a file with two columns of data, let's say:

```
kevin n1

edwin n2

mevin n3
```

I would like to generate a statement with something like this.

```
--This is kevin and his 'roll number' is n1

--This is edwin and his 'roll number' is n2

--This is mewin and his 'roll number' is n3
```

Now, I am unable to do this with `awk`. It doesn't like dash lines "--" or single quotes (') in the middle of the statement.

I would like the output to be in the way I have shown above?

Comment: Could you please share _what_ you have tried, and the actual error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NF{print "--This is " $1 " and his \047roll number\047 is " $2 }' file
```

`\047` is the octal code the for single quote `'`.

Another alternative is to define a variable holding the single quote character:

```
awk -v sq="'" 'NF{print "--This is " $1 " and his "sq"roll number"sq" is " $2 }' file
```

Comment: I have see that if we don't have a space before and after $2, it fails unless I put $2 in double quotes. I am sorry I am new to this and just know basic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `while` loop:

```
while read -r name roll; do if [[ -z "$name" ]]; then echo ; else echo "--This is $name and his 'roll number' is $roll"; fi; done < infile
--This is kevin and his 'roll number' is n1

--This is edwin and his 'roll number' is n2

--This is mevin and his 'roll number' is n3
```

This solution preserves the blank lines, as it seems to be OP's wishes.

`infile` looks like below:

```
cat infile 
kevin n1

edwin n2

mevin n3
```

This is void of error handling et al, and of course depends on the file being in the format as specified by OP.

Comment: Sorry, the blank lines were not intentional. When I was typing in the question, I saw that the output I am typing in was coming in a single line, in the preview window. So, I had to intentionally put in a new line in between.

Answer (score 0):

perl one-liner:

```
perl -ane '@F && printf "--This is %s and his '\''roll number'\'' is %s\n", @F' file
```